# ASP.NET Core Remove DNX Core 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

If I have a reference to this in ASP.NET 1 core it seems to me that if this is present
I can not have code that relies on .NET 4.6 with the DNX Core 5.0 present. I removed the reference from project.json

```
"frameworks": {
"dnx451": { },
"dnxcore50": { }
```

},

When i did this Visual Studio locked up and I had to use Task Manager to shut it down.Is there a way to disable this reference without removing from project.json.

Comment: I have this too sometimes. This happens sometimes, when you change project.json. After a restart you should be able to edit it correctly though. The freezing itself is not related to removing of dnxcore or dnx451, it can happen with any change to project.json

Comment: Such hang issues are impossible to be fixed soon, as the tooling is still in preview (Microsoft just published Preview 2.0.1 if you go to http://dot.net). Visual Studio Code might be a better tool to use when editing such files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is targeting dnx, it was created in version RC1 or before.  You should go through all the steps outlined [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html) to update it to Core 1.0.

There were a lot of changes when RC2 came out.  The depreciation of dnx is just one of them.  If you did not uninstall all ASP.NET 5 components before upgrading to ASP.NET Core, you're better off uninstalling Visual Studio 2015 and all ASP.NET 5/Core components and then install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and ASP.NET Core 1.0.

Comment: I don't think uninstalling the whole VS is necessary.

Comment: @svick - Take it from someone who's been there.  If you don't uninstall all ASP.NET 5 components before upgrading to Core, VS hangs on to little bits of ASP.NET 5 that cause all sorts of weird problems.  Can you solve all those problems?  Maybe.  But you'll spend 10x the amount of time fixing those problems than it would take to uninstall and re-install.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use DNX, use latest identifiers.**

Refer this-

[image: Monikers]

Reference:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#deprecated-monikers

Comment: Is there a way to target 4.5.1? With out editing project.json?

Comment: Yes, you can use `net451` instead of your `dnx451`.

Comment: @PaulStanley: Just see my comment. Just edit it after you restarted VS2015. This freezing of VS can happen **anytime** you edit the project.json. Not related to the removal of the target moniker

Comment: @Sanket thanks How do I  use net451 instead of dnx451 ?

Comment: You can just replace dnx451 and use net451 in framework section of project.json. But check Tseng comment above. If its related to just freezing of VS then he is correct.